# can't close socket connection on KeyboardInterrupt(Python)

Tags: python, networking, python-sockets

[image: Code Image]

I'm trying to close socket connection(currently I'm printing out classMember @ line 60) but it's not working on KeyboardInterrupt, What should I do?

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors; see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Add `self.socket.close()` before your `break` statement.